# Make recyclerview rows share a common parent

Tags: android

How do I make some of the recyclerview rows to be children of the same viewgroup?

In this screen you see the title "popular" ( which is a also a row of the recyclerview), and below it is a viewgroup (white background) containing other recyclerview rows

[image]

Edit: In this screen , everything you see other than the toolbar and the bottombar are row layouts of a recyclerview. Now please check the rows which say "Mexican Burger Menu" and "Barbecue Burger". Those two are children of a single viewgroup with white background. How?

Comment: You mean recycler view with multiple view types, right?

Comment: were u able to solve ur problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple view types . override get view type method and inside create view get view type and work for different views

Comment: #pulp_fiction no I am unable